# How do I get Dapper.Rainbow to insert to a table with AutoIncrement on SQLite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, dapper, dapper-rainbow

I created a sample table on SQLite that has an Id column that is auto increment.

```
CREATE TABLE "ESVLIntegration" ("Id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , "ProcessId" TEXT NOT NULL , "UserId" INTEGER NOT NULL , "Status" TEXT NOT NULL , "StartDate" DATETIME NOT NULL , "EndDate" DATETIME, "Operation" TEXT NOT NULL , "SNEquip" TEXT NOT NULL , "CardName" TEXT NOT NULL , "FilePath" TEXT NOT NULL , "Processed" BOOL NOT NULL )
```

But when I try to insert for the second time, I get the following error:

> Abort due to constraint violation PRIMARY KEY must be unique

This is my code

```
public class ESVLIntegration
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public String ProcessId { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public String Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public String Operation { get; set; }
    public String SNEquip { get; set; }
    public String CardName { get; set; }
    public String FilePath { get; set; }
    public Boolean Processed { get; set; }
}

public class Sample : Database<Sample>
{
    public Table<ESVLIntegration> ESVLIntegration { get; set; }
}

private void WriteParameters()
{
    "Writing sample parameters to SQLite DB".LogDebug();
    var pars = new ESVLIntegration();
    pars.ProcessId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    pars.CardName = "gpp3";
    pars.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
    pars.Status = "Start";
    pars.Operation = VerifyStatus;
    pars.SNEquip = "12345";
    pars.FilePath = @"C:\Folder\FilePath";
    pars.Processed = false;
    using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(connStr))
    {
       conn.Open();
       var db = Sample.Init(conn, 2);
       db.ESVLIntegration.Insert(pars);
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here ?

***EDIT***

INTEGER columns on SQlite are of type int64(long)

Comment: you are going to need to hack the rainbow source to get it to work

Comment: I got it working just fine as per my answer. Setting the key field as nullable did the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the SQLite FAQ I found :

> With this table, the statement
>
> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(NULL,123);
>
> is logically equivalent to saying:
>
> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES((SELECT max(a) FROM t1)+1,123);

So I just changed my class Id to be nullable

```
public class ESVLIntegration
{
    public long? Id { get; set; }
    public String ProcessId { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public String Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public String Operation { get; set; }
    public String SNEquip { get; set; }
    public String CardName { get; set; }
    public String FilePath { get; set; }
    public Boolean Processed { get; set; }
}
```

Now it works great!